# Zina, promise of marriage

Tags: zina, forgiveness

I was dating a boy, we fell in love. We committed zina with the intention of marriage later, (this doesn't help my situation) My father found out, I was kicked out of my family home as a disgrace. My family have disowned me now.

1) is it permissible for me and this
man to marry? Will our marriage be haram?

I have no mahram, what can the man do, who does he ask for my hand? My father said I am not his daughter and disowned me.

2) will a marriage based on haram things like zina be blessed by Allah? Or is it doomed to fail?

3) I need forgiveness from Allah for my sins, what can I do?

Comment: Here some relevant Questions http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28467/i-had-premarital-sex-with-my-cousin-now-i-have-questions-about-marriage?lq=1 http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30309/is-a-woman-allowed-to-marry-a-man-once-she-was-in-touch-with?lq=1 http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30020/question-regarding-adultery http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/18753/intercourse-before-marriage http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28069/sexual-sin-before-marriage http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29089/can-my-husband-ask-my-hand-from-my-uncle-not-my-dad

Comment: I think the links above would give you the necessary information you may need to answer your major questions. What you'll have to do both is do sincere repentance first. Then your boy friend -assuming he is willing to marry you- should ask your father (maybe both of you should find person you trust which can act as a mediator and whom will attend your bf) if your father still rejects him. You can chose an other wali for example your uncle to give his accordance! Saying you have no mahram is wrong any male relative like father, brother who is prohibited to marry you is a mahram.

Answer (score 1):

Good info posted above.
My opinion:
1. yes permissible. Try to reach out to a relative for help if not father
2. As long as u both truely repent
3. ask forgiveness and check online for duas.

Comment: Please consider elaborating your answer to make more useful. I strongly suggest you to add references to support your claims.

Comment: Certain answers are based on common sense and need no reference

Comment: @Kamran we are not a peer support either a question can be answered by some kind of evidences or a kind of logical explanation etc..The opinion of an unknown person rather looks like an advise and is far away from an expert answer and therefore is not what this site is meant for.